# Assign Function to Initialized Variable in For Loop?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

A question regarding the variable initialized in a for-loop:

The setup:

```
from urllib import urlopen

WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"

WORDS = []
```

My question is, when loading up the words from the url into the empty list WORDS, why does this work:

```
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL):
    WORDS.append(word.strip())
```

While this doesn't?

```
for word.strip() in urlopen(WORD_URL):
    WORDS.append(word)
```

Per my understanding, a function can be called on the initialized variable in a for loop, as long as the type of said variable supports that function.

In this case, the type of the initialized variable is a string with a newline at the end, so I would think that `word.strip()` would work. Instead, I get the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Why is this?

Comment: Assignment (including in `for` statements) doesn't work like that - you assign values to *names*, not to *expressions*. Thought experiment: if this worked, what would `for "an actual string literal".strip() in urlopen(WORD_URL):` do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: As I understand word is a name; i.e., a variable created on the fly in the for loop. If strip() can be called on word in one area, why can't it in another? Also, I ran your code through the interpreter and it gave the same error as above--not really understanding--thank you for your patience in advance--but could you please elaborate with more code examples?

Comment: The point is that `for` loops are (repeated) assignments, and you can only assign to names. `word.strip()` is an expression, which just happens to contain a name (two, in fact - `strip` is also a name). The point is that the reason you can't do what you're trying to do is that it doesn't really make any sense. How about `for len(word) in some_list:` or `for a + b in some_list:` - how is Python supposed to know which name you really want to assign to, and how the rest of the expression relates to that?

Comment: That clarified it for me; I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand now; what I was trying to do wasn't working because:

```
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL):
```

Is an expression designed to iterate over some object, so calling the strip() method on the newly minted variable word doesn't make sense at this point.

The obvious answer was to simply call the strip() method on the variable word inside of the for loop block.

@Zero Piraeus your patience is appreciated.